# How can I force a webview login on SDK 3.1.1 using openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions in iOS 6?

Tags: authentication, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I got this code from the facebook tutorial:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    @"email", 
    @"user_likes",
    nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                         state:state
                                                         error:error];
                                 }];
```

}

But it always opens a Safari Tab.
**I need to force a webview login instead of Safari Tab.**

Thanks in advanece!

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately there seems to be no public api to force this behavior.
There is work around (i.e just create your own session and set this as active session and use

```
    [session openWithBehavior:howToBehave
                    completionHandler:handler];
```

If you observe the source code for openActiveSessionWithPermissions in github

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions
                            allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                      allowSystemAccount:(BOOL)allowSystemAccount
                                  isRead:(BOOL)isRead
                         defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
                       completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler {
    // is everything in good order?
    [FBSession validateRequestForPermissions:permissions
                             defaultAudience:defaultAudience
                          allowSystemAccount:allowSystemAccount
                                      isRead:isRead];
    BOOL result = NO;
    FBSession *session = [[[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil
                                               permissions:permissions
                                           defaultAudience:defaultAudience
                                           urlSchemeSuffix:nil
                                        tokenCacheStrategy:nil]
                          autorelease];
    if (allowLoginUI || session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        // we open after the fact, in order to avoid overlapping close
        // and open handler calls for blocks
        FBSessionLoginBehavior howToBehave = allowSystemAccount ?
                                                FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent :
                                                    FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView;
        [session openWithBehavior:howToBehave
                completionHandler:handler];
        result = session.isOpen;
    }
    return result;
}
```

you can also use 
    - (id)initWithAppID:(NSString*)appID
            permissions:(NSArray*)permissions
        urlSchemeSuffix:(NSString*)urlSchemeSuffix
     tokenCacheStrategy:(FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy*)tokenCachingStrategy;

to create session , if you use `[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions]` , info.plist file should have key FacebookAppID with your aphid as value

so the equivalent of this code will be

```
[FBSession setActiveSession: [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions] ];             

        [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            switch (status) {
                case FBSessionStateOpen:
                    // call the legacy session delegate
                    //Now the session is open do corresponding UI changes
                    break;
                case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                { // prefer to keep decls near to their use

                    // unpack the error code and reason in order to compute cancel bool
                    NSString *errorCode = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode];
                    NSString *errorReason = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedReason];
                    BOOL userDidCancel = !errorCode && (!errorReason ||
                                                        [errorReason isEqualToString:FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue]);

                    // call the legacy session delegate if needed
                    //[[delegate facebook] fbDialogNotLogin:userDidCancel];
                }
                    break;
                    // presently extension, log-out and invalidation are being implemented in the Facebook class
                default:
                    break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
            }
        }];
```

Note: 1)In the equivalent code i skipped to validate the permissions

Comment: can u brief the code means what code should in appdelegate and what should be in loginviewcontroller.

Comment: You made me very happy by posting this!  :)

Comment: @ravi For login things are happening smoothly. But for `reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions` I tried using `reauthorizeWithPermissions` which is called in the github code, but the call back for the method is  not happening. Instead the `openWithBehavior` method is being called again

Comment: I am logging in using this method, and taking `@"publish_actions"` permission while logging in.  
I try to logout using `closeAndClearTokenInformation`. It sort of logs out, but when the next time I try to login, it doesn't ask for username and password! It just opens the webview for a moment, then the webview disappears with a successful login. I verified that the account is not logged in in safari

Comment: @neeraj:
 1) When you use "FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView" you need to logout using the Facebook.h instance method [facebook logout] - which also takes care of clearing the cookies in the web view , also make sure to remove cookies from "https://m.facebook.com" also in FBSession.m +deletefacebookCookies method .
2)@discussion Methods and properties that specify permissions without a read or publish
 qualification are deprecated; use of a read-qualified or publish-qualified alternative is preferred
 (e.g. reauthorizeWithReadPermissions or reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions)

Comment: @ravi I can't find the objecti for "Facebook" using which I can call the "logout" method. But I went to the "invalidate" method, and copied the statements required for deletion of cookies. That clears the cookies, but doesn't completely logout. Probably the sign in information is still in there. The next time I try to login, the web view opens and then closes with successful login.  
  
I am trying to delete cookies for "login.facebook.com" and "m.facebook.com", but for m.facebook.com no cookie informatin is fetched.

Comment: @neeraj:  [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
 [FBUtility deleteFacebookCookies]; will take care of logout

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSArray *permissions = @[@"basicinfo",etc...];
 FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
 [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
 [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {}];
```