# Facebook iOS 3.7 FacebookAppId

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I just installed from pkg the SDK 3.7 for Facebook.

I see that I need to put there a value for `FacebookAppId`. However I have 2 apps: one for testing and one for production.

Since I need to support variables for Debug and Release, I am using an Environment file which determines the value based on the configuration value. (Debug or Release)

How can I "tell" the SDK to use the relevant one for each release type, without changing it manually when building it?

I didn't check in the source code. Just the compiled one.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate `to use the relevant one for each release type, without changing it manually when building it?`

Comment: i don't think you could do it without changing it manually.

Comment: @Shadowfax I mean, that I will use an enviornment.plist for debug and release and based on the property there facebook would know to pick the right FacebookAppId

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560512/ios-facebook-sdk-define-facebookappid-remotely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Preprocessor macros over here..

How to use it :

1. Go to Build settings of your project.
2. Search "Preprocessor macros". Here define your macros like for eg **FBDebugAPPID** for debug moed & **FBReleaseAPPID** for release mode.
3. FBSettings class used to override the default facebook AppId.

   Then after add below code in your delegate method..

   ```
   #if defined(FBDebugAPPID)
   **Use your debug app id**
   [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"DEBUGAPPId"]
   #elif defined(FBReleaseAPPID)
   **Use your release app id**
   [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"RELEASEAPPId"]
   #endif
   ```

Hope it resolve your problem..

Comment: I can't control "FacebookAppId" as Facebook is looking for it in their source code

Comment: you can override the default FacebookAppId Settings. FBSettings class provide required methods for that.
1) + (void)setDefaultAppID:(NSString*)appID;// For override
2) + (NSString*)defaultAppID; // Retrieve default AppID from .plist.

Comment: I will check it! Can you update your answer with the method to put in appDelgate?

Answer (score 0):

You can change you enviornment.plist variables by adding a run script build phase

**To add a Run Script Build Phase in Xcode**

1. Select your application target in your project, then select "Build Phases".
2. In the menu bar, click "Editor", select "Add Build Phase", and then click on "Add Run Script Build Phase".
3. You should now see a Run Script section in the middle of your Build Phase options, as shown above.
4. Inside the body of the Run Script Build Phase, paste in the script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :FacebookAppID 321" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
else
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :FacebookAppID 321" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach,

Recent Xcode project templates already have a DEBUG=1 macro defined for the Debug build configuration.

[image]

You can use it in combination with `#ifdef`

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define FACEBOOK_APP_ID                     @"FB_DEVELOPMENT_ID"

#else
    #define FACEBOOK_APP_ID                     @"FB_PRODUCTION_ID"
#endif
```